# Sitecore - Transfer a site from one installation to another

Tags: database, serialization, content-management-system, package, sitecore

I am running Sitecore 6.5

I have two installations of Sitecore and want to transfer a whole site from one installation to another.

Have found a few articles that go into Serialization and Creating a Package although they don't go into detail about how these two fit together.

How do I transfer a site from one installation to another?

thanks.

Comment: Do you just need to transfer data, or files as well. Do you have a Visual Studio solution with complete source code and configuration for the install?

Answer (score 5):

Create a package with the package designer.
include these items and their children with the button "items statically". if you have placed your solution specific item in folders, it is only needed to include these.

- /sitecore/content
- /sitecore/layout
- /sitecore/media library
- /sitecore/templates/ (only take the templates you have created. e.g. the folder user defined

using the button "files statically", include the folders with  you have solution specific changes to like:

- /bin
- /layouts
- /app.config/include (only take the files changed in the solution,
  compared to a default sitecore installation)
- web.config (if you have made changes to this, compared to default
  sitecore web.config)

if you have any user accounts you want to transfer to, you can include them with "security accounts".

then generate zip file and install on empty sitecore and full publish :)

Comment: You should avoid adding the /sitecore/templates/sytem folder! If you do this you won't be able to install the package because of a circulair reference.

Comment: that was what i ment with Items in solution specific foldes. I always place the templates i create for a solution in a folder in sitecore/templates/user defined/-SolutionName-/. But i see my explanation of this was bad :)

Comment: Would an alternative be to serialize the item, dump into the other instance and run an Update Database in the Developer Tab which will bring in the items? Or is this a separate thing altogether?

Comment: Dappergoat: Does mentioned above do the database too?

Comment: i have very bad experience with the serializing, and have only used it once because of this. 
After creating this package you install it on an empty sitecore solution of the same version and revision (find it on sdn.sitecore.net). But if you just want a complete copy of the site, you could detach the databases from the sql(or what you are using) server. Copy them and insert the new databases in the sql server. Then copy the entire website folder and change the connection string to the new databases.

Comment: Will only installing packages work for moving sitecore instance from one machine to another? Actually I created packages from old environment, for all the section of sitecore instance e.g. Layout, Template, Media, Content,Forms, System, and now I am installing the packages on my machine. DO I need database backups also? I do not have database backups for Sitecore instance.

Answer (score 2):

If your systems are similar enough, you may want to consider moving the Sitecore DBs via backup/restore (in SQL) and copying over filesystem assets.  Generally I find this faster and less prone to user error than creating/installing very large packages. (Just remember to take back-ups first.)

Answer (score 0):

Large packages have a tendency to break, one option would be to look into this:

http://www.hhogdev.com/Products/Team-Development-for-Sitecore/Overview.aspx

TDS can sync all your items to XML on your dev box and from that you can create a different sort of installation package which is significantly more robust than a regular package you create through the Sitecore desktop. It's the same sort of package that Sitecore use when you upgrade versions.

I believe there is a 60 day trial on this product so plenty of time to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Note: when transferring user accounts, passwords will not be migrated when using either packages or serialization.

Solution is here - cowboy-aspx from Sitecore :)
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631